# define a scala variable scope

Tags: scala, hadoop, scala-collections

I am new to this area and was trying basic things but got stuck in a simple variable scope issue.

In this below code I want to use "item" through out the program and want to print it's value. But while I am using "item" inside a foreach loop it's considering it as local variable and it's value is not available out side the loop.

Could you please let me know where I am wrong ?

```
import scala.collection.immutable._

val set1=Set()
val set2=Set("A","B","C")
var item:String=null

println(set1.isEmpty)
println(set2.head)
println(set2.tail)

set2.foreach{item => if (item != "A") println(item)}

println(item)
```

Result:

true
res0: Unit = ()
A
res1: Unit = ()
Set(B, C)
res2: Unit = ()

B
C
res3: Unit = ()

**null** // expected that it will take last result of the foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `foreach` you are creating a new variable with the same name so it "shadows" the existence of the first `item`.

`x =>` is the syntax for naming the parameter(s) passed to the anonymous function that follows.

It sounds like you want something similar to this...

```
set2.foreach{x => item = x; if (item != "A") println(item)}
```